# Clone table and filter out rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I got a question regarding cloning a table.

I want to filter out some specific results and output those results.
Let me explain myself better with HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="ProfileList2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2014-02-28 21:12:12</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>166</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2014-03-01 14:04:35</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2014-03-03 15:22:56</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>2014-03-03 17:15:56</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>2014-03-03 17:50:49</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>2014-03-05 17:33:42</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p class="result"></p>
```

In my Javascript I want to filter out all the results that have within the last `<td>` or every `<tr>` the value 0.

```
var $mainTable = $("#ProfileList2");
var $training = $mainTable.clone("tr td:nth-child(5):not(:contains('0'))");

$('p').append($training);
```

This code will clone a direct copy without doing any filtering.
If I change the `clone` function to, for example: `find` function, it will only return the table-data: 166  21  21  24.

Is there any function available that will return the whole table-row instead of only the table-data?

[JSFIDDLE OVER HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/xt9pjhhd/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grab the table rows, change this:

```
$mainTable.find("tr td:nth-child(5):not(:contains('0'))")
```

… to this:

```
$mainTable.find("tr td:nth-child(5):not(:contains('0'))").parent()
```

Also note that a `paragraph` element cannot contain a `table` element according to the specification.  (Although most browsers allow it.)  Changing it to a `div` would be better.

[**Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/udjqjens/)

---

Also note that the contains selector will search for a 0 *within* the cell, so it will match cells containing "160" as well as those containing "0."

Instead, you could filter to exclude only cells that equal "0":

```
$mainTable
  .find("tr td:nth-child(5)")
  .filter(function() {return $(this).text() != '0';})
  .parent();
```

[**Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/udjqjens/2/)

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I am looking for and Indeed I will change it to a `<div>`! Thanks for your advise!

Comment: instead of `.find("tr td:nth-child(5)")` can use `.find("tr td:last-child")`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could copy the whole thing and then filter out what you don't like, how about that?

```
var copy = $("#ProfileList2").clone();

$('p').append(copy);

copy.find("tr td:nth-child(5):contains('0')").parent().remove();
```

Make note that it is not a good idea to have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Interesting! :) I prefer the method of @Rick Hitchcock but this method is also quite good! Thanks!

Comment: @Rotan075 I assumed you wanted to keep the old table, since you have written "clone" in the title, that is why I suggested cloning, if you need to move rows you should also create a 2nd table.